# How do I link my 2nd folder with my first folder using Relative Links in HTML?

Tags: html, hyperlink, relative-path

My first folder is called Tests.
Inside Tests, I've got a HTML file called Tomel.
Using relative link, I stated:

```
<p> Here's <a href= "Test2/Jasser.html"> THE IRQI WANNABEE KURD'S Page </a> </p>
```

Which links Tomel's file to Jasser and it works.

However, to do the reverse and go back from Jasser to Tomel, I stated:

```
<p> <a href="../Test2/Tomel.html"> Tomel's Page </a> </p>
```

But it doesn't work. Help me out here please.

Answer (score 0):

> `../Test2/Tomel.htm`

Tomel's Page inside inside the `Test2` directory, but that is where you are looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

From ur information provided
Your directory should look like

```
Tests/
|
---Tomel.html
---Test2/
    |
    ---Jasser.html
```

Therefore, if you using the following in **Tests/Tomel.html**

```
Test2/Jasser.html
```

No error as your current directory is **Tests/**
and **Tests/Test2/Jasser.html** exists

However, if you are in **Tests/Test2/Jasser.html**, if you do the following

```
../
```

You current directory will become **Tests/**, therefore, **Tomel.html** is at the same directory

So the answer for Jasser to Tomel should be

```
../Tomel.html
```